# Rails: Implementing a search form for compound filtering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a model containing products. I would like to create a search form to allow users to apply compound filters to products as required. For example:

- Products with a price of between '10' (text field) and '50' (text field) with a colour of 'Red', 'Green' or 'Blue' (check box fields) and a weight of 'Less than' (select field) '5kg' (text field).

There will be a considerable number of fields that a user can filter by -- some, all, or none of them may be specified.

I am aware that the above can be achieved by using named scopes, lots of conditional logic (case and if statements) and Rails form helpers, but is there a cleaner and more efficient way? Perhaps there is a gem/plugin to provide this functionality that I have overlooked?

Any advice much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I went with [meta_search](http://github.com/ernie/meta_search), which seems to offer most of the functionality of [searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic), but with Rails 3 support.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the plugin searchlogic:

- Original plugin: [binarylogic/searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic)
- My fork, with support to sorting by polymorphic association fields: [nandalopes/searchlogic](http://github.com/nandalopes/searchlogic)

Comment: Unfortunately, searchlogic doesn't appear to support Rails 3.